# best practice for merging multiple arrays dynamically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm looking for the best practice for merging dynamic arrays.
For example, when I got arrays like this.

```
object 1 : {time : 20180420100000 , id : label01 , values : 25.0 }
object 2 : {time : 20180420101005 , id : label01 , values : 26.0 }
object 3 : {time : 20180420101010 , id : label01 , values : 26.5 }
object 4 : {time : 20180420100000 , id : label02 , values : 100 }
object 5 : {time : 20180420100020 , id : label02 , values : 1.0 }
object 6 : {time : 20180420100020 , id : label03 , values : 2.0 }
```

I want to merge values by object's time without removing duplicates, and the values must be ordered by label. I set label counts by 3 here but the number can be vary.

The result would be

```
                                // [label01, label02, label03]
{time : 20180420100000, values : [25.0, 100, ""] }
{time : 20180420100005, values : [26.0, "", "" ] }
{time : 20180420100010, values : [26.5, "", "" ] }
{time : 20180420100020, values : ["",  1.0, 2.0 ] }
```

The values can be string type.
How can I effectively get this?

Comment: [From the `java` tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java): "*Java (**not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS**) [...]*"

Comment: @Turing85 Maybe it's Java, but I don't think that even matters.

Comment: To the OP, you can create a new JSON object, whose keys are time, and whose values are JSON arrays.  Then, iterate your current JSON object, and populate those arrays.